# Occurs on the lock screen [ Performing stop of activity that is already stopped : {package.LockScreenActivity} ]

Tags: android, android-activity, lockscreen

I implemented the Android lock screen app.

> An RuntimeException occurred while executing the LockScreenActivity(Regardless of the Android version).
>       But this Exception is occurs very intermittentl and it is not reported to Crashlytics.

The Exception content is :

```
2018-11-20 16:09:10.037 7657-7657/hanmo.com.drinkingwaterassistant E/ActivityThread: Performing stop of activity that is already stopped: {hanmo.com.drinkingwaterassistant/hanmo.com.drinkingwaterassistant.lockscreen.LockScreenActivity}
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is already stopped: {hanmo.com.drinkingwaterassistant/hanmo.com.drinkingwaterassistant.lockscreen.LockScreenActivity}
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:4200)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:4288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap25(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

First, I reproduced this intermittent exception to occur when I wanted to.

The conditions for reproduction are as follows.

- Given : The lock screen Activity is running.
- When : startActivity to transparent activities
- Then : occurs Exception that (performing stop of activity that is already stopped)

Style for transparent activity :

```
<style name="transparentView" parent="android:Theme.Translucent">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

> Occurs when transparent Activity appeared on the lockScreenActivity.
>
> > So I made a non-transparent lockScreenActivity.  However, Exception persisted intermittently.
>
> **I want to know the cause of this Exception.**

---

***Here are my suspicious parts of LockScreenActivity.***

**Manifest**

```
<activity android:name=".lockscreen.LockScreenActivity"
        android:showOnLockScreen="true"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance" />
```

**onWindowFocusChanged in LockScreenActivity**

```
override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            if (hasFocus) window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    )
        }
    }
```

**onAttachedToWindow in LockScreenActivity**

```
override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
        )

        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        super.onAttachedToWindow()
    }
```

**Admob in LockScreenActivity**

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/transparent"
            app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            app:adUnitId="@string/admobBanner"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

---

> And My LockScreenActivity Example is [here](https://github.com/hanmolee/LockScreenKotlinExample)

Comment: Except for the anxious part `onWindowFocusChanged`, I tried the test, but the exception occurred consistently. I also tried to handle the `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD` and `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` of `onAttachedToWindow` in `onCreate`, but I experienced the same exception.

Comment: I checked the logcat to see what happens on other lock screen apps that I have created.